# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush does not seem to be working when receiving an object destructured from a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am using the OnPush strategy, I have a service that updates some data, when I receive it in the component I have to click on the screen to see changes on the screen.

```
Parent.ts
    // Click start the logic
    click() {
       this.showChild = true;
       setTimeout(()=> this.update, 0); // Hack to show the loading in the component until it receives a value from the service
    }
    update() {
    this.explorer.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.info = {...data};
      // this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
Parent html
<app-child *ngIf="showChild" [info]="info" [otherVar]="otherVar"></app-child>
```

I understood that when using the destructuring there would be a reference change but I don't see it working. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Variable info needs to be a @input Property in another Component to get the .OnPush <> reference change functionality

Comment: I have supplemented the answer. The variable this.info I send it to a child component and it doesn't work.

Comment: issue can't be reproduced from what's here. something else is going on in your app. you'll need to provide more details or recreate the bug in a stackblitz

Comment: Is it possible that you have changed the changeDetectionStrategy from the Parent Component also to .onPush?

That would explain your Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a little example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9kg67). Using OnPush everywhere with the [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
Parent.ts
    // Observable Variable declaration
    info$: Observable<InfoModel>;
    // Click start the logic
    click() {
       this.showChild = true;
       setTimeout(()=> this.update, 0); // Hack to show the loading in the component until it receives a value from the service
    }
    update() {
    // instead of subscribing here, retrieve just the Observable
    this.info$ = this.explorer.getData();
  }
Parent html
<!--<app-child *ngIf="showChild" [info]="info" [otherVar]="otherVar"></app-child>-->
<app-child *ngIf="showChild" [info]="info$ | async" [otherVar]="otherVar"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference changes triggers a change detection on a component with OnPush change detection strategy only if it's on an *@Input*

Comment: I have supplemented the answer. The variable this.info I send it to a child component and it doesn't work.

Comment: as @Crazybutch said, what's the change detection strategy of your parent component?

Comment: All have on push, 
The problem I think comes because the child component is quite heavy (it is a calendar with 10 months), I think it takes longer to load than receiving the response from the service, and there I think the problem is, I don't know how to handle these kinds of situations

Comment: You should remove the OnPush on the parent as it validates my answer : this..info being changed inside the subscription in the parent, the OnPush strategy doesn't update its value without triggering the change detection manually.